# how to design a database to do fast range query on 2 fields (min and max)

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-design, sphinx, database

We have a database of all the ip location. It's designated like

```
min_ip
max_ip
location
```

I need to retrieve as fast as possible the row like

```
where min_ip > xxx and max_ip < xxx
```

The problem, only one index can be use in most database design (index on min_ip)
so query are always a little slow. even when database can use 2 index, it's still slow because internally they do 2 query (where min_ip > xxx) and (where max_ip < xxx) and after merge the result.

Is their any trick to make this query run fast? we use mongodb and sphinx as database engine right now

Comment: I'd be more concerned that the query as you have it now will return _no_ rows :-) I think you meant `where xxx > min_ip and xxx < max_ip` (or their "or-equal-to" variants).

Comment: yes i write to fastly )) it's where xxx > min_ip and xxx < max_ip

Comment: Could you clarify what an ip location is? Is it a number? A string? What does it mean to compare `xxx` to an ip location? Can you edit the question to include a sample document?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to setup indexing a geoip database with a RTree index, see for example
http://blog.jcole.us/2007/11/24/on-efficiently-geo-referencing-ips-with-maxmind-geoip-and-mysql-gis/

Possibly can do this in mongodb, it looks like there might be RTree indexes.

(I dont think sphinx would be a good fit for this. Not sure its indexing structure is suited to this. It might be able to run the query quite quickly simply beause it always holds attributes in memory, but its not indexed, so a proper index should still beat it)

Answer (score 0):

First, not all databases allow use for only one index. MySQL and MariaDB have index merge access method, which combines use of multiple indexes.

You could also change the way you store your data, and thus enable range queries against it. Instead of storing min_ip, max_ip, optionally make location a unique index, and store location, min-ip, location, max_ip as separate records.
Then you can use range queries for min_ip, max_ip.

The third option would be to use a spatial index, and CONTAINS operator. PostgreSQL, MySQL implement it. With Tarantool, an RTree index is stored in memory, so you can expect an instant response if your data footprint is moderately small (a few gigabytes to a few hundred gigabytes).